# Dependency Injection with global objects (sessions)

Tags: dependency-injection, immutability

**TL;DR**: My question is about how to use in conjunction:

- the dependency injection design pattern
- with global / immutable objects (ex: a session that references a customer object)

I get the idea of dependency injection and immutable objects. They are great concepts and help implement good development practices. *Is there a way to make these work together?*

The scenario is from a PHP background. We have a global variables that represent session information. Most every implementation will write a wrapper class to handle persisting updates to the session data.

Let's say our session wrapper has two settings:

- is logged in
- customer id

This is simple if we inject the session wrapper as a dependency without trying to have the object be immutable. Any recipient of the session wrapper can set either properties.

Is there ideas for how to make this scenario work with immutable objects? My thought is "no" but I may not be seeing the entire situation properly.

Comment: If you make the session wrapper inmutable, how come any recipient of it could set its properties? Inmutable is inmutable for everyone.

Comment: You are asking how to make an immutable object that people can modify? That doesn't make sense as by definition if it is immutable you cannot modify it... Most DI Frameworks will allow you to replace to de-register and then re-register an object, so you could simply do that if you want to replace the whole object with a new one instead of modifying the existing one. If you explained what you were actually trying to achieve you may get a sensible answer but at the moment it seems like you have already decided a solution that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts. It does seem that this wasn't possible. I appreciate it.